# NestJS Microservice with rabbitmq without pattern

Tags: rabbitmq, nestjs

I have one rabbitmq service that have a queue with no schema json in message.

Like this:

```
{"customFieldOne": "foo", "another": "bar", "numbers": [3, 5, 8]}
```

But nestjs with rabbitmq needs a json schema, like this:

```
{"pattern": "my-pattern", "data": {"fieldOne": 1 ...}}
```

It must have the pattern and data field.

Is there any way to consume any json message without a pattern or schema defined?

In my code I consume using pattern but I need to consume any data from rabbitmq with nestjs microservice.

```
@MessagePattern('my-pattern')
// @EventPattern('my-pattern')
getNotifications(@Payload() data: number[], @Ctx() context: RmqContext) {
  console.log(data);
  console.log(`Pattern: ${context.getPattern()}`);
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked into a [custom transporter](https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport)?

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party but I had similar issue with MQTT in Nest.

To remove pattern and transport only data, I've added this code inside `something.module.ts`.

```js
{
  name: 'HYPERVISOR_CLIENT',
  transport: Transport.MQTT,
  options: {
    url: process.env.MQTT_URL ?? 'mqtt://localhost:1883',
    protocolVersion: 5,
    serializer: {
      serialize(value, options?) {
        return value.data
      },
    },
  },
}
```

This results in a clean output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

NestJS is highly opinionated and all of its messaging microservices - whether RabbitMQ (which is actually AMQP, *not* MQTT) [https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/rabbitmq], MQTT [https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/mqtt], or Custom Transporters [https://docs.nestjs.com/microservices/custom-transport] - require the use of @MessagePattern or @EventPattern, depending on whether you publish or emit respectively.

If you want to send a message to MQTT without the prerequisite of needing to define either a message-pattern or event-pattern yourself, you will need to by-pass NestJS standards and write code based on first principles using the 'npm mqtt' library.

The following is an example and based on my own experiences and is little more than a compilation of the examples provided in https://www.cloudamqp.com/docs/nodejs_mqtt.html#cloudamqp-with-mqtt-and-nodejs--getting-started and https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#example and https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js#aliased-wildcard-import:

```
import * as mqtt from 'mqtt';

export class AppService {

  sendToMqtt(p_oData): void {

    const options = {
      port: parseInt(process.env.MQTT_PORT),
      username: process.env.MQTT_USER,
      password: process.env.MQTT_PASS,
      /** 
       * This clientId is recommended by mqtt's own documentation.
       * It is a random value and there is no further reference to it
       * in the documentation.
       */
      clientId: 'mqttjs_' + Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 8)
    };
    
    const oClient = mqtt.connect(
      `mqtt://${process.env.MQTT_HOST}`,
      options
    );
    
    oClient.on("connect", () => {

      console.info("connected");

      const json = JSON.stringify(p_oData);

      oClient.publish(process.env.MQTT_TOPIC, json, () => {
        console.info("Message is published");
        oClient.end(); // Close the connection when published

        oClient.on("end", () => {
          console.info("Client disconnected");
        });

      });

    });

  }

}
```

For the above to work, you would need to supply a .env with the following settings (modify with your settings):

```
MQTT_USER=<your_username>
MQTT_PASS=<your_password>
MQTT_HOST=<your_mqtt_host_domain>
MQTT_PORT=1883 // This is the standard MQTT port
MQTT_TOPIC=<the_topic_you_want_to_publish_against>
```

Just in case it's not clear, and you haven't done so already, you will need to install mqtt (although it's likely you will have done this if you already tried to use NestJS microservices for RabbitMQ or MQTT:

```
npm install mqtt --save
```